# Linux command to put a CD/DVD in the tray

Tags: command-line, dvd

I know that there is an `eject` command in Linux to open the DVD tray:

```
eject /dev/sr0
```

But what command is used to put a disk in the tray?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any – unless your computer has a robotic arm attached, but those very rarely have standardized commands for this sort of operation. Otherwise you will have to do it manually. (You might have better luck with [automated tape libraries](https://youtu.be/EfrKAP3VdZA) instead.)

There is, however, `eject --trayclose` for closing the DVD tray once a disc has been inserted or removed via other means. (Only works with motorized trays, not 'slim' laptop ones.)